# Laravel Horizon worker constantly crashes silently

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, supervisord, laravel-horizon

We are running Laravel 7 and [Horizon 4.3.5](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/horizon). Horizon runs with Supervisor.

We have 10 different queues configured, but workers responsible for one particular queue constantly dies without any output. After restarting Horizon, I can see these workers up and running for several seconds via `top` and `ps` commands. Then they are gone.

I checked supervisor's `stdout_logfile`: nothing suspicious there. I can see Jobs related to this queue are being processed successfully. Each worker processes **exactly** 2 jobs before crash.

I checked supervisor's `stderr_logfile`, but it's empty.

Laravel logs and `failed_jobs` table both are empty.

I even checked `syslog`, but nothing related there.

There are no problems with other queues at all. Only this particular queue keeps piling up: jobs are being pushed to queue by application, but never processed until I restart Horizon.

There are lot of free space on disk, free RAM, CPU usage is low.

Worker command: `/usr/bin/php7.4 artisan horizon:work redis --delay=0 --memory=128 --queue=main --sleep=3 --timeout=1800 --tries=1 --supervisor=php01-Mexm:business`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out it was **Out Of Memory** problem. We had one job in this queue which caused crash.

Still not sure why logs were empty. Probably there wasn't enough memory to log anything.